# ThreadPool with controlled task affinity in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Hi I would like to have a thread pool class, which ensures that certain tasks will be executed in the same thread. See this simple API:-

```
class ThreadPoolWithAffinity{
// All tasks with the same key should be queued to the same thread
  void EnqueueTask(Task t, Key k); 
}
```

Is there some library that have already invented "the wheel"?

Comment: No such thing is built-in or available through the ParallelExtensionExtras. Why do you need that?

Comment: Suppose you have several web clients consumers, waiting for events and suppose sending an event is relatively long operation which you prefer to do in parallel by creating task of sending ceratin event and placing it to TP. To preserve the order of events you need that all tasks created for sending events to certain client be handled by the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose you have several web clients consumers, waiting for events and
>   suppose sending an event is relatively long operation which you prefer
>   to do in parallel by creating task of sending ceratin event and
>   placing it to TP. To preserve the order of events you need that all
>   tasks created for sending events to certain client be handled by the
>   same thread

Not at all. You simply need to start tasks only when all dependencies are completed. No need to use the same thread.

Let's say you want to make requests A, B, C and D with the following dependencies:

```
A and B independent
B after A
C after A and B
```

Then you write:

```
Task a = RequestAsync("A");
Task b = RequestAsync("B");
Task c = a.ContinueWith(_ => RequestAsync("C")).Unwrap();
Task d = Task.WhenAll(a, b).ContinueWith(_ => RequestAsync("D")).Unwrap();
```

All dependencies are now set up. You can also dynamically add work.

You can build arbitrary DAGs that way.

Comment: Not sure I get it. What do you do if the number of task is unlimited and not given at the beginning of the run? Just like mails arriving one after another?

Comment: You can attach continuations at any time. If a mail comes in you simply set up the dependencies at that point. You can also use await (`await c; await RequestAsync("C");`).

Comment: Indeed you are right about that order of operation does not imply that every task should be executed by the same thread. However what you suggest is implementation details, e.g.  that's how one might implement the API above. I am looking for ready made implementation of the API for something that seamed to me as a very common problem.

Comment: What more "ready made" do you expect? This is very minimal code. Only your app knows what dependencies there are. No framework can automatically discover them. Maybe if you provide more details on what you are trying to do I can suggest something simpler. Are the dependencies DAGs or simply chains?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like TPL is what you want, especially [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd991174(v=vs.110).aspx). Example:

```
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        DoSomeLongComputation();
    });
    // This task will start as soon as the first is finished
    task1.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        DoAnotherLongComputation();
    });
```

If you build a `Dictionary<Key, Task>` that assigns tasks to keys, you can enqueue new tasks using `ContinueWith()`.

Comment: That assumes you have the list of tasks @hand. But I do not also task1 may finish well before the continuation task is ready. Think about handling RSS notifications. Everything from the same source should be handled by the same thread.

Comment: @Boris you just pinged user at-hand. He got a notification to his inbox.